# Как не отправлять по форме пустые данные?

Tags: javascript, html

Отправляю по GET  запросу форму, URL Очень длинный от того что отправляются пустые данные, на стороне сервера они (null).

Как запретить отправку пустых данных по форме ?

Comment: HTML5 умеет проверять формы на корректность, в т.ч. и обязательные поля.

Answer (score 0):

сделай проверку отправляемых данных 
например :

```js
let formElement =  document.querySelector('#form')
formElement.addEventListener('submit',(ev)=>{
  let  formData = new FormData(formElement);   
   for (var value of formData.values()) {
    if(value.length ===0){
      ev.preventDefault() // если нет полей - то остонавливаем выполнение события 
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<form id = "form" >
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" >
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" v>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

ev.preventDefault() - останавливает дефолтное выполнение события